# buttons and listviews

Tags: c#, asp.net

i have two listviews and each one contains an linkbutton.
if i press the lb from the first listview it fires up an event but when i press the lb from the second one it dosen't. but if i put the lb just above the second listview it fires it up.

first listview:

```
<asp:ListView ID="ListViewMesaje" runat="server">
    <LayoutTemplate>
        <ul>
            <asp:PlaceHolder ID="itemPlaceholder" runat="server" />
        </ul>
    </LayoutTemplate>
    <ItemTemplate>
        <asp:LinkButton ID="LinkButtonStergeMesaj" runat="server" CommandName="stergeMesaj"
                                        CommandArgument='<%#Container.DataItem%>' OnCommand="LinkButtonListView_Click"><div id="mesajdelete" class='<%#getBackgGifMesaj(getUsernameMesaj((string) Container.DataItem,"citit"))%>'></div></asp:LinkButton>
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:ListView>
```

second one:

```
<asp:ListView ID="ListViewFriendRequests" runat="server" DataSourceID="SqlDataSourceFriendRequests" >
        <LayoutTemplate>
            <ul>
                <asp:PlaceHolder ID="itemPlaceholder" runat="server" />
            </ul>
        </LayoutTemplate>
        <ItemTemplate>
            <asp:LinkButton ID="LinkButtonfqignora" runat="server" CommandName="refuzaPrieten"
                                        CommandArgument='<%#Eval("username")%>' OnCommand="LinkButtonListView_Click"><div id="friendreqign" >'<%#Eval("username")%>'</div></asp:LinkButton>
        </ItemTemplate>
</asp:ListView>
```

Comment: What version of .net are you using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally found an answer why the buttons inside a listview don't get fired up.
If your using an SqlDataSource as your DataSource you need to declare SelectCommand, UpdateCommand, DeleteCommand and InsertCommand for the sqldatasource, like this:

```
<asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server"
                   ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:Pubs %>"
                   SelectCommand="SELECT [au_id], [au_lname], [au_fname], [state] FROM [authors]"
                   UpdateCommand="UPDATE [authors] SET [au_id] = @au_id, [au_lname] = @au_lname,[au_fname] = @au_fname, [state] = @state WHERE [au_id] = @original_au_id"
                   DeleteCommand="DELETE FROM [authors] WHERE [au_id] = @original_au_id"/>
```

At first i just declared the SelectCommand, and that's why the buttons didn't got fired up.

Answer (score 0):

Two suggestions:  Have you tried removing the DataSourceID attribute, since that seems to be the main difference between the two?

Also, it's better to subscribe to the ListView's Command event instead of subscribing directly to the link button's command event.  When the command even fires on the button, the event will bubble up and the listview will take it and fire its own event with the relevant info.